# Given $\sup|f(x)|=A$ and $\sup|f''(x)|=C$, prove $\sup|f'(x)|\leq \sqrt{2AC}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Problem: Let $f$ be twice differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ with $\sup|f(x)|=A$ and $\sup|f''(x)|=C$. Prove that $\sup|f'(x)|\leq \sqrt{2AC}$.

Hint: If $f'(x_0)=b>0$, show that $f'(x_0+t)\geq b-C|t|$. Integrate from $x_0-b/C$ to $x_0+b/C$.

Attempt: 
I can't understand how to work through the hint, so I tried the following.
Let t>0. By Taylor's Theorem, $f'(x_0+t)=\frac{1}{h}[f(x_0+t)-f(x_0)]-tf''(c)$ for some $c\in (x_0+t,x_0+2t)$. Thus 
\begin{align}
|f'(x_0+t)|&= \left|\frac{1}{t}[f(x_0+t)-f(x_0)]-\frac{t}{2}f''(c)\right|\\
&\leq \frac{f(x_0+t)}{t}+\frac{|f(x_0)|}{t}+\frac{t}{2}|f''(c)|\\
&\leq \frac{A}{t}+\frac{A}{t}+\frac{Ct}{2}\\
&= \frac{2A}{t}+\frac{Ct}{2}
\end{align}
I still need the last expression to be less than or equal to $\sqrt{2AC}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The estimate as you found it seems to be too weak as $\frac{2A}t+\frac{Ct}2\ge 2\sqrt{AC}$ (AM-GM)

Comment: I forgot to mention that; thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use the hint directly:
By the MVT have $f'(x_0+t)-f'(x_0)=tf''(\xi)$ with $\xi$ between $x_0$ and $x_0+t$, hence $|f'(x_0+t)-f'(x_0)|\le C|t|$, i.e., $$ f'(x_0)-C|t|\le f'(x_0+t)\le f'(x_0)-C|t|.$$
Thus for $x_0\in \Bbb R$ and $a> 0$,
$$\begin{align}
f(x_0+a)-f(x_0-a)&=\int_{-a}^af'(x_0+t)\,\mathrm dt\\
&\ge \int_{-a}^a(f'(x_0)-C\left|t\right|)\,\mathrm dt\\
&=\int_{-a}^0(f'(x_0)+Ct)\,\mathrm dt+\int_{0}^a(f'(x_0)-Ct)\,\mathrm dt\\
&=2a f'(x_0)-a^2C
\end{align}$$
and 
$$\begin{align}
f(x_0+a)-f(x_0-a)&=\int_{-a}^af'(x_0+t)\,\mathrm dt\\
&\le \int_{-a}^a(f'(x_0)+C\left|t\right|)\,\mathrm dt\\
&=\int_{-a}^0(f'(x_0)-Ct)\,\mathrm dt+\int_{0}^a(f'(x_0)+Ct)\,\mathrm dt\\
&=2a f'(x_0)+a^2C.
\end{align}$$
From the bound for $f$ we know $-2A\le f(x_0+a)-f(x_0-a)\le 2A$ so that ultimately
$$\frac{-2A-a^2C}{2a}\le f'(x_0)\le\frac{2A+a^2C}{2a}.$$
For the specific choice $a=\sqrt{\frac{2A}{C}}$ this leads to
$$ -\sqrt{ 2AC}\le f'(x_0)\le\sqrt{2AC}$$
as desired.

Comment: What would prevent us from saying that, since $|f(x_0+a)-f(x_0-a)|\leq 2A$, we have $\frac{-2A}{2a}\leq f'(x_0)\leq \frac{2A}{2a}$? If this is true, then choosing $a=\sqrt{\frac{A}{2C}}$ should do it.